# Laravel login not working - once new session is required the credentials are no longer valid

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a application while testing i've noticed that the login system:

- If I create a account, it work fine.
- If I logout and log back in, it works fine.
- If I wait a period of time, and the users session is no longer valid, the same credentials are no longer valid.

What could effect the program in this way and where are they located?

I created the authorisation using the standard command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Answer (score 0):

All file is here

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth
```

If you use phpstorm IDE you can press ctrl+left click in class name and phpstorm open that file.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
```

Comment: Thanks! Would their be any common causes for this?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that would cause this behaviour.